# How do I use a like statement with multiple values while excluding the values that I don't want?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

My query is as below, but that will return records that have rules 494, 788, plus any others. How do I limit it to return records that have just those two rules?

```
select * from result where rules like '%494%'
AND rules like '%788%'
AND tradedate >= '2014-01-01'
```

Sample record in the rules column looks like this: |406|407|759|398|399|381|702|

I want to return all records that have 494 AND 788, but if they have any other rule ID's, I don't want them.

Comment: Do the rules start with those numbers?

Comment: Can we see some full examples of what the `rules` column might contain? Be sure to include some that should pass, and some that shouldn't.

Comment: An example column looks like this:

|702|494|14|788|

But ultimately, I only want to see the records that have 494 and 788. If it has anything else, I don't want it.

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you normalized your rules table. You seem to have a bunch of delimited values in a single column.

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a lot easier if these tables were normalized. Since it's not clear whether rules appear in any particular order when multiple rules apply to a specific record, you want to account for all possible combinations. This should give you all the results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM result 
WHERE rules IN ('|494|', '|788|', '|494|788|', '|788|494|')
AND tradedate >= '2014-01-01'
```

If you ever need to query for more than combinations of one or two rules, you'll run into a lot of difficulties down the road if you're not storing these in a separate normalized table with one rule per row. In the current form, you have n^2 possible combinations to check for, where n is the number of rules being checked.

Comment: This was helpful. It didn't get me exactly what I wanted, but pointed me in the right direction. The rules are in numerical order, so it will always be 494, 788, though there could be some in between. So by simply querying for these, ('|494|','|494|788|'), I have what I need. (I don't care about 788 by itself, which I should have clarified earlier). Momentary laps in smarts, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this (assumes that you have a list of rules you want to exclude):

```
SELECT *
FROM result
WHERE rules IN ('494', '788', ...etc...)
```

If you use

```
... rules LIKE '%494%' AND rules LIKE '%788%'
```

this will only return records with rules such as '494788'

If you use

```
... rules LIKE '%494%' OR rules LIKE '%788%'...
```

this will return rules such as '1494' and '4944' because you have a wildcard on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from result where (rules like '%494%'
OR rules like '%788%')
AND tradedate >= '2014-01-01'
```

The OR will make sure that both rules are applied separately, and the brackets ensure that both will still be compared with trade date.

If you dont want anything from rules like 14942 or 27885, remove the % symbols from the appropriate side (percent is wildcard for any number of characters, including none), or use the appropriate operator (probably = in this case)